# Looking for a django app for running my blog

Tags: django, blogs

I am looking for a django blog application to run my blog.

I have found following options available:

- django-basic-blog
- Byteflow

Can you please share your recommendation.

My basic requirements are:
- Easy to customize
- Having basic blog capabilities

Comment: I haven't used either of those solutions, but it's really fun to write your own blog in Django. It's not very hard either - most of the work for writing a simple application like a blog is done for you, and it's a good way to learn to use Django.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[django-mingus](http://github.com/montylounge/django-mingus)

Recommended.

Comment: yes and it is quite easy to deploy, in my case, on WebFaction.

Answer (score 1):

Try [django-diario](http://code.google.com/p/django-diario/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommended Byteflow
This project has great promise. 
I myself included in the project soon